# PHP: Cannot retrieve correct ajax response using curl or file_get_contents

Tags: php, ajax, curl, http-headers, file-get-contents

1. [Start page](http://www.icefilms.info/ip.php?v=1148&)
2. [Frame page](http://www.icefilms.info/membersonly/components/com_iceplayer/video.php?h=374&w=631&vid=1148&img=)
3. [End page](http://www.icefilms.info/membersonly/components/com_iceplayer/GMorBMlet.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.megaupload.com%2F%3Fd%3DVNICBFWL&w=631&h=392)

I can't figure out what I'm missing. I've tried mimicking the firefox request headers, but it doesn't work.

Also, the frame page reaches the end page using a javascript ajax request. It posts the data to `$post_to_link` (see code below) then navigates to the `expected result` (not my `current result`), where the megaupload link is located.

Expected output:

```
/membersonly/components/com_iceplayer/GMorBMlet.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.megaupload.com%2F%3Fd%3DVNICBFWL&
```

Current output:

- `file_get_contents` outputs `3`
- curl outputs error 403 forbidden access

Here is my code:

```
    // call it like so...
    echo GetHosterLink( 1148, 252636, '', '37fn8Oklq', 15, -75 );
    // $s is incremented every second you are 'visiting' the referer page
    // $m decreases below zero when you move your mouse `down` on the start page

    function GetHosterLink( $id, $link_id, $cap, $sec, $s, $m )
    {

        $link_page = str_replace( '[ID]', $id, 'http://www.icefilms.info/membersonly/components/com_iceplayer/video.php?vid=[ID]' );
        $post = "id={$link_id}&s={$s}&iqs=&url=&m={$m}&cap=&sec={$sec}&t={$id}";

        $header = implode( "\r\n", array(
            "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
            "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7",
            "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate",
            "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5",
            "Cache-Control: no-cache",
            "Connection: keep-alive",
            "Content-Length: " . strlen( $post ),
            "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
            "Host: www.icefilms.info",
            "Pragma: no-cache",
            "Referer: http://www.icefilms.info/membersonly/components/com_iceplayer/video.php?h=374&w=631&vid={$id}&img=",
            "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:8.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0"
        ));

        $opts = array('http' =>
            array(
                'method'  => 'POST',
                'header'  => implode("\r\n",
                    array(
                        'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                        'Content-length: ' . strlen( $post ),
                        'Referer: ' . $link_page . '&h=374&w=631',
                        'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:8.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0',
                        'Host: www.icefilms.info'
                    )
                ),
                'content' => http_build_query(
                    array(
                        'id' => $link_id,
                        's' => $s,
                        'sec' => $sec,
                        't' => $id,
                        'm' => $m,
                        'iqs' => '',
                        'url' => '',
                        'cap' => ''
                    )
                )
            )
        );

        $context  = stream_context_create($opts);

        $post_to_link = 'http://www.icefilms.info/membersonly/components/com_iceplayer/video.phpAjaxResp.php';
        $get_result = file_get_contents( $post_to_link, false, $context );

        $f_result = cURL::DoRequest( $post_to_link, $post, '',
            array( array( CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header ) ) );

        $f_r = array(
            'result' => $f_result,
            'get_result' => $get_result,
            'get_opts' => $opts,
            'get_response' => $http_response_header,
            'req_post' => $post,
            'req_href' => $post_to_link,
            'req_header' => $header
        );

        return ( $f_r );

    }
```

Here is my `curl.php` file:

```
class cURL
{

    public static function DoRequest( $url, $post = '',
        $cookie_file = '', $variables = array() )
    {

        $curl = curl_init();
        @session_start();
        $cookie = ( 'PHPSESSID=' . session_id() . '; path=/' );
        @session_write_close();

        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie );

        if ( !empty( $cookie_file ) )
        {

            curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file );
            curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file );

        }

        if ( !empty( $post ) )
        {

            //curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
            curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post );

        }

        foreach ( $variables as $var )
            curl_setopt( $curl, $var[0], $var[1] );

        $result = curl_exec( $curl );
        curl_close( $curl );

        return ( $result );

    }

}
```

Comment: I can't figure out what you're missing either. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @HelgiHrafnGunnarsson I'm trying to visit the frame page, grab the `sec` variable and post the information to the `$post_to_link` to retrieve the megaupload link. None of my approaches past or present give the correct output, it's either encoded(?), a number or 403 forbidden.

Comment: Site probably uses sessions, so you have to have valid session.

Comment: @webarto If you look at my curl class, you'll notice I enforce the same session from my site onto the webpage. If you mean they use session variables, then maybe.

Comment: Probably [this answer is helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8636363/367456).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try visiting initial page (the one's url you have in `$link_page`) with curl and make sure the file you point to in:

```
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie );
```

exists and is writeable.

Then request the `$post_to_link` url with same curl resource.

By visiting the initial page you are getting cookies and making sure there is a valid session for your next request. That also secures the referer you then provide in headers. There are many ways to figure "automatic" requests, and things like checking cookie and if you actually visited "referer"-ed link are quite common.

Comment: +1 i also guess this is a session/cookie protected members area. using curl to login, obtain a cookie and re-use the stored cookie seems to be the right track.