# Unable to fetch my schedule data from my schools site. Login with cURL won't work

Tags: php, curl, screen-scraping

**Edit:** Why the minus one?

What I am trying to do is the following:

- I am trying to login to my school site using cURL and grab the schedule to use it for my AI.

So I need to login using my pass and number, but the form on the school site also needs a hidden 'token'.

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="becb14a25acf2a0e697b50eae3f0f205" />
    <input type="text" name="user" />
    <input type="password" name="password" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

I'm able to successfully retrieve the token. Then I try to login, but it fails.

```
// Getting the whole website
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.school.com');
$data = curl_exec($ch);

// Retrieving the token and putting it in a POST
$regex = '/<regexThatWorks>/';
preg_match($regex,$data,$match);
$postfields = "user=<number>&password=<secret>&token=$match[1]";

// Should I use a fresh cURL here?

// Setting the POST options, etc.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);

// I won't use CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER yet, first I want to see results. 
$data = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

Well... It doesn't work...

- Is it possible the token changes every curl_exec? Because the site doesn't recognize the script the second time...
- Should I create a new cURL instance(?) for the second part?
- Is there another way to grab the token within 1 connection?
- Cookies?

Comment: cUrl just does request the way you commands it to. In your case you obviously fails to make the right settings for the request, so it fails. Anyway, you might be more looking for some browser automation than cUrl.

Comment: The ultimate goal is to display the schedule on my site. Why did I deserve a -1 btw? I'm trying to understand cURL.

Comment: cUrl is very good, but it only does what you tell it. In your question you just tell it to get a page, but how a login works and all that stuff, has nothing to do with cUrl actually. As written, you might be looking for a better browser automation.

Comment: @Hakre: You seem to possess good knowledge. Please help this inferior mignon with his codes. In other words... Could you check my 'solution'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I solved it. The problem was probably the 'not-using-cookies' part.
Still this is probably 'ugly' code, so any improvements are welcome!

```
// This part is for retrieving the token from the hidden field.
// To be honest, I have no idea what the cookie lines actually do, but it works.
$getToken= curl_init();
curl_setopt($getToken, CURLOPT_URL, '<schoolsite>');       // Set the link
curl_setopt($getToken, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies.txt');  // Magic
curl_setopt($getToken, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies.txt'); // Magic
curl_setopt($getToken, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);         // Return only as a string
$data = curl_exec($token);                                 // Perform action

// Close the connection if there are no errors
if(curl_errno($token)){print curl_error($token);}
else{curl_close($token);} 

// Use a regular expression to fetch the token
$regex = '/name="token" value="(.*?)"/';
preg_match($regex,$data,$match);

// Put the login info and the token in a post header string
$postfield = "token=$match[1]&user=<number>&paswoord=<mine>";
echo($postfields);

// This part is for logging in and getting the data.
$site = curl_init();
curl_setopt($site, CURLOPT_URL, '<school site');
curl_setopt($site, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies.txt');    // Magic
curl_setopt($site, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies.txt');   // Magic
curl_setopt($site, CURLOPT_POST, 1);                     // Use POST (not GET)
curl_setopt($site, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfield);      // Insert headers
$forevil_uuh_no_GOOD_purposes = curl_exec($site);        // Output the results

// Close connection if no errors           
if(curl_errno($site)){print curl_error($site);}
else{curl_close($site);}
```

Comment: @SuperSpy: If you're interested in how you could make this more easy to use, checkout my answer now, which is a bit lengthy but this might be what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8636363/367456

Answer (score 1):

What's the error message you get? Independently of that; your school's website might check the referrer header and make sure that the request is coming from (an application pretending to be...) its login page.

Comment: I get no error message. Just a blank page. Could it be that the school site doesn't 'recognize' the script the second time? And thus creates a new token for it? Is there another way to grab the  token within 1 connection?

Comment: nah I don't think it's the token. I'd try setting the referer to the URL of the login form. Also check if the login form is starting a session and send any cookies back that you might have received. And of course I'm assuming you're doing all this with only the best intentions ;)

Comment: Best intentions, of course :) Could you briefly explain how cURL works with cookies?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I somehow did it :) Please check if you can improve my solution :)

Answer (score 1):

As you're building a scraper, you can create your own classes to work for what you need to do in your domain. You can start by creating your own set of request and response classes that deal with what you need to deal with.

Creating your own request class will allow you to implement the curl request the way you need it. Creating your own response class can you help you access/parse the returned HTML.

This is a simple usage example of some classes I've created for a demo:

```
# simple get request
$request = new MyRequest('http://hakre.wordpress.com/');
$response = new MyResponse($request);
foreach($response->xpath('//div[@id="container"]//div[contains(normalize-space(@class), " post ")]') as $node)
{
    if (!$node->h2->a) continue;
    echo $node->h2->a, "\n<", $node->h2->a['href'] ,">\n\n"; 
}
```

It will return my blogs posts:

```
Will Automattic join Dec 29 move away from GoDaddy day?
<http://hakre.wordpress.com/2011/12/23/will-automattic-join-dec-29-move-away-from-godaddy-day/>

PHP UTF-8 string Length
<http://hakre.wordpress.com/2011/12/13/php-utf-8-string-length/>

Title belongs into Head
<http://hakre.wordpress.com/2011/11/02/title-belongs-into-head/>

...
```

Sending a get request then is easy as pie, the response can be easily accessed with an xpath expression (here [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)). XPath can be useful to select the token from the form field as it allows you to query data of the document more easily than with a regular expression.

Sending a post request was the next thing to build, I tried to write a login script for my blog and it turned out to work quite well. I needed to parse response headers as well, so I added some more routines to my request and response class.

```
# simple post request
$request = new MyRequest('https://example.wordpress.com/wp-login.php');
$postFields = array(
    'log' => 'username', 
    'pwd' => 'password',
);
$request->setPostFields($postFields);
$response = new MyResponse($request->returnHeaders(1)->execute());
echo (string) $response; # output to view headers
```

Considering your scenario you might want to edit your own request class to better deal with what you need, mine already uses cookies as you're using them, too. So some code based on these classes for your scenario could look like:

```
# input values
$url = '<schoolsite>';
$user  = '<number>';
$password = '<secret>';

# execute the first get request to obtain token
$response = new MyResonse(new MyRequest($url));
$token = (string) $response->xpath('//input[@name="token"]/@value');

# execute the second login post request
$request = new MyRequest($url);
$postFields = array(;
    'user' => $user, 
    'password' => $password,
    'token' => $token
);
$request->setPostFields($postFields)->execute();
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/OtahKC) and [code as gist](https://gist.github.com/1521174).

If you want to further improve this, the next step is that you create yourself a class for the "school service" that you make use of to fetch the schedule from:

```
class MySchoolService
{
    private $url, $user, $pass;
    private $isLoggedIn;
    public function __construct($url, $user, $pass)
    {
        $this->url = $url;
        ...
    }
    public function getSchedule()
    {
        $this->ensureLogin();

        # your code to obtain the schedule, e.g. in form of an array.
        $schedule = ...

        return $schedule;
    }
    private function ensureLogin($reuse = TRUE)
    {
        if ($reuse && $this->isLoggedIn) return;

        # execute the first get request to obtain token
        $response = new MyResonse(new MyRequest($this->url));
        $token = (string) $response->xpath('//input[@name="token"]/@value');

        # execute the second login post request
        $request = new MyRequest($this->url);
        $postFields = array(;
            'user' => $this->user, 
            'password' => $this->password,
            'token' => $token
        );
        $request->setPostFields($postFields)->execute();

        $this->isLoggedIn = TRUE;
    }
}
```

After you've nicely wrapped the request/response logic into your `MySchoolService` class you only need to instantiate it with the proper configuration and you can easily use it inside your website:

```
$school = new MySchoolService('<schoolsite>', '<number>', '<secret>');
$schedule = $school->getSchedule();
```

Your main script only uses the `MySchoolService`.

The `MySchoolService` takes care of making use of `MyRequest` and `MyResponse` objects.

`MyRequest` takes care of doing HTTP requests (here with cUrl) with cookies and such.

`MyResponse` helps a bit with parsing HTTP responses.

Compare this with a standard internet browser:

```
Browser: Handles cookies and sessions, does HTTP requests and parses responses.

MySchoolService: Handles cookies and sessions for your school, does HTTP requests and parses responses.
```

So you now have a school browser in your script that does what you want. If you need more options, you can easily extend it.

I hope this is helpful, the starting point was to prevent written the same lines of cUrl code over and over again and as well to give you a better interface to parse return values. The `MySchoolService` is some sugar on top that make things easy to deal with in your own website / application code.

Comment: You code is great! It is a really good for tutorial purposes. Thank you. I've got one more question (keep in mind that I'm a OO noob): Quote:'my request uses always cookies because I know it needs them' How do you know that? When does a request need a cookie? And also, what does RuntimeException do? And the '__toString()' pert? All those questions...

Comment: Well generally I don't know if the request needs cookies or not, but in the concrete case, we know it needs cookies, as the code is written for the concrete case, they are in. `RuntimeException` is just an [`Exception`](http://php.net/Exception). I use Exceptions to signal the error cases, like if an URL can not be requested. And [`__toString`](http://php.net/__toString) allows an object to be treated as string which was handy in the example.